# JSON keys with decimal points not in order

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have keys in a JSON file and when processed with the keys are not in numerical order. Any way to fix this?

```
$.getJSON("file.json", function(thedata) {
  var items = [];
  $.each(thedata, function(key, val) {
    items.push(key);
  });
```

The JSON file:

```
"3.5":"some data",
"8":"some data",
"13":"some data",
"17.5":"some data",
"18":"some data",
```

They keys will come through in this order: `8, 13, 18, 3.5, 17.5`

Comment: JSON just stores data as it receives it, there's no inherent ordering of any kind. I'd just order it afterwards.

Comment: Object keys do not have an order. If order is important, use an array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JSON object properties have no order, so an object created by deserializing JSON may have the properties in any order.*

You can get the keys, sort them, and then loop through the properties:

```
$.getJSON("file.json", function(thedata) {
  var items = [];
  Object.keys(thedata)
    .sort(function(left, right) { return left - right; })
    .forEach(function(key) {
      var val = thedata[key];
      // Use `key`, `val`...
    });
});
```

Live copy without the `$.getJSON` part:

```js
var json =
    '{"3.5":"some data",' +
    '"8":"some data",' +
    '"13":"some data",' +
    '"17.5":"some data",' +
    '"18":"some data"' +
    '}';
var thedata = JSON.parse(json);
var items = [];
Object.keys(thedata)
  .sort(function(left, right) { return left - right; })
  .forEach(function(key) {
    var val = thedata[key];
    console.log(key + " = " + val);
  });
```

Alternately, return the data as an array of arrays, in order:

```
[
    ["3.5", "some data"],
    ["8", "some data"],
    ["13", "some data"],
    ["17.5", "some data"],
    ["18", "some data"]
]
```

then:

```
$.getJSON("file.json", function(thedata) {
    thedata.forEach(function(entry) {
        var key = entry[0], val = entry[1];
        // Use `key`, `val` here
    });
});
```

Live example (without `$.getJSON`):

```js
var json =
    '[' +
        '["3.5", "some data"],' +
        '["8", "some data"],' +
        '["13", "some data"],' +
        '["17.5", "some data"],' +
        '["18", "some data"]' +
    ']';
var thedata = JSON.parse(json);
thedata.forEach(function(entry) {
    var key = entry[0], val = entry[1];
    console.log(key + " = " + val);
});
```

If you can use ES2015+ features (you only support cutting-edge browsers, or you transpile), you can use destructuring assignment in that `forEach`:

```js
const json =
    '[' +
        '["3.5", "some data"],' +
        '["8", "some data"],' +
        '["13", "some data"],' +
        '["17.5", "some data"],' +
        '["18", "some data"]' +
    ']';
const thedata = JSON.parse(json);
thedata.forEach(([key, val]) => {
    console.log(key + " = " + val);
});
```

---

* As of ES2015, JavaScript object properties do have an order, at least for certain operations, but it's not usually useful to rely on that order.

Comment: there is a dupe of sort order of new es, but i cannot find it actually, there is the rule, integers, as keys for arrays are sorted first, then the rest.

Comment: @NinaScholz: Yes, [details here](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-ordinaryownpropertykeys): Within an object, it's properties whose names match the definition of an [integer index](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-object-type), numerically, first; then other keys in the order in which the properties were created. But only for the new operations defined in ES2015, not `for-in` or `Object.keys` (although AFAICS, SpiderMonkey and V8 at least follow this order for those, too).

Answer (score 1):

You can get keys with `Object.keys()` and use `sort()` method.

```js
var obj = {
  "3.5": "some data",
  "8": "some data",
  "13": "some data",
  "17.5": "some data",
  "18": "some data"
}

var keys = Object.keys(obj).sort((a, b) => a - b);
console.log(keys)
```

If you also need values you can use `Object.entries` and sort by first element in arrays which will be the keys.

```js
var obj = {
  "3.5": "some data",
  "8": "some data",
  "13": "some data",
  "17.5": "some data",
  "18": "some data"
}

var entries = Object.entries(obj).sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0]);
console.log(entries)
```

Comment: While this sorts the keys, I would assume that the OP wants the values associated with the keys too. Could be wrong, though as their intent is not entirely clear.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan if OP want the values associated with keys, just do one more map: `.map(key  => obj[key])` :)

Comment: Yes actually I would need the values with the keys although this is some nice useful code to quickly grab the keys.

Comment: Not sure how that gets the values as well?